# Variable con valor por defecto PHP

Tags: php, php7

Quisiera resolver este codigo en una linea como se haria en javascript, pero para php.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == LOCAL_DOMAIN) {
    $ip = '170.55.81.114'; /*dev */
}
```

Que en JS seria algo como,

```
const ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == LOCAL_DOMAIN && '170.55.81.114'
```

Comment: si mi respuesta soluciono tu problema recuerda marcas como resuelto, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP hay [operaciones ternarias](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) que es lo que se hace en javascript:

Siguiendo tu ejemplo, estas regresando la IP, pero si no entra al `if` php generara un warning y te dira que $ip es null:

```php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == LOCAL_DOMAIN) {
    $ip = '170.55.81.114'; /*dev */
}
```

En este caso con la operacion ternaria estarias devolviendo la `ip` o `null` que es esactamente lo mismo pero evitando el warning:

```php
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == LOCAL_DOMAIN ? '170.55.81.114':null;
```

A todo esto si el script se va a ejecutar desde CLI, es importante saber que en dicho entorno no existe la super global `$_SERVER` por ende no existira `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` como control se puede hacer esto:

```php
$ip = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == LOCAL_DOMAIN) ? '170.55.81.114':null;
```

Con esto se valida que exista y al mismo tiempo que concuerde con el valor esperado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, habia intentado hacer eso pero con isset y me estaba dando error. Veo que para tal caso no es necesario utilizar isset.

Comment: el isset es un control de error por ejemplo seria valido si tu script debe ejecutarce desde un CLI